# AM I doing this right? - How many binary words of length 8 are there that contain at least six 1's?

Tags: permutations, factorial, combinations

How many binary words of length 8 are there that contain at least six 1's?

This is what I have:

8!/6!2! = 28 words

Is this the correct answer?

Comment: That's the number of permutations of words that contain **exactly** 6 ones.  You also want to count those that contain 7 or 8 ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but that only counts those containing **exactly** 6 ones.

You want to count those containing **at least** 6 ones; meaning those containing 6, 7, or 8 ones.

Use the same principle and add them together.

$$\frac{8!}{2!6!}+ \frac{8!}{1!7!}+\frac{8!}{0!8!} = 37$$

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.